# Object prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, prototypal-inheritance, prototype-programming

I tried the following code snippet:

```
var man = new Object();
man = {sex : 'male'}
var child = new Object(man);
child.firstName = 'foo'
child.lastName = 'bar'
Object.getPrototypeOf(child);
```

This returns *Object {}*, while I expected it to return the object associated with *man*. However, this snippet:

```
var man = Object.create(null);  
man = {sex : 'male'}
var child = Object.create(man);  
child.firstName = 'foo'  
child.lastName  = 'bar'

Object.getPrototypeOf(child);
```

It does return the object associated with *man*. Conceptually, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Whats wrong in that?

Comment: `var man = new Object();` doesn't do anything for you; you replace the value immediately afterward with an object literal. Is the same as if you did `var man = { sex: 'male' };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that is what it is specified to do.  The `Object` constructor simply coerces its argument to an object - it does not do anything with the prototype:

> When the Object constructor is called with no arguments or with one argument value, the following steps are taken:
>   1. If value is supplied, then
>       a. If Type(value) is Object, then
>       i. If the value is a native ECMAScript object, do not create a new object but simply return value.
>   http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.2.1

`Object.create` on the other hand, sets the prototype:

> 1. If `Type(O)` is not `Object` or `Null` throw a `TypeError` exception.
> 2. Let obj be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression `new Object()` where `Object` is the standard built-in constructor with that name
> 3. Set the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of obj to O.
>      http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.5

Answer (score 1):

I think the conceptual misunderstanding lies in what you think `new Object()` does. if you pass an object into `new Object()`, the new object will have whatever properties that object has. However, it does not create a new object with the prototype of the original object, it just takes each property and adds it to the newly created object.